# Using RegEx to grab a field in brackets

Tags: regex, perl, splunk

I have multiple square bracketed data in the log file of a splunk log. I am attempting to find a particular field named UserDataGuid and then gather the data in the bracket after this. My only option seems to be regular expressions in a standard that seems similar to perl to me. Yet does not work what am I doing wrong here ?

```
   | rex "\]\s(?<UserDataGuid>.*?)\s*$"

   // this trial looks more promising but grabs the last bracket :( and doesn't name the field, to be used in a subSearch.
  | rex "(?i)UserDataGuid\s*\[([^\}]*)\]
```

the data looks like this

```
[21] INFO UserDataGuid [fas08f0da-faf6-4308-aad6-hfld5643gs] [(null)] [(null)] [(null)]
```

and I want only the guid

```
fas08f0da-faf6-4308-aad6-hfld5643gs
```

and I would love for it to be a field I could reuse like fields are used in splunk.

Comment: Why did you write this: `[^\}]*`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try the following regex:

```
(?<=UserDataGuid \[).*?(?=\])/g
```

This will capture `fas08f0da-faf6-4308-aad6-hfld5643gs`. See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/yK4qC8/1).

Comment: It is wrong to get into the habit of adding `/gmis` to the end of every pattern you write. In this case you want to find only the first occurrence of the pattern; you have no `^` or `$` so `/m` has no effect; you want to match `UserDataGuid` -- `userdataguid` will not do; and you're not interested in strings that span newlines. So *none* of those modifiers are useful

Comment: @Borodin, yes I agree with you on  flags /gmis. However, based on limited knowledge of input string, it could be multiline capture so to be on safe side, I added this, assuming OP knows what being done and can adjust based on needs. I'm not capturing `^` or `$` so /ms are irrelevant. However, g (global) is required as OP may have many more captures than just one.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
\]\s(?<UserDataGuid>.*?)\s*$
```

you say: match a *]* **>** `\]`, follow by any space character (only one) **>** `\s`, follow by a group with name *UserDataGuid* **>** `(?<UserDataGuid> ... )` that contains any character, except newline (zero times, to unlimited times) **>** `.*?` ( in lazy mode, **?** ), follow by any space character (zero times, to unlimited times) **>** `\s*`, follow by end of string **>** `$`

I think that you don't want this `(?<UserDataGuid> ... )`;
you want match (in some way) `UserDataGuid`, no call `UserDataGuid` at the group that match " any character, except newline (zero times, to unlimited times) **>** `.*?` ( in lazy mode, **?** ) "

In

```
(?i)UserDataGuid\s*\[([^\}]*)\]
```

change the **}**, for a **]**, and then, you captured your GUID in group #1

but, you don't need match "*UserDataGuid\s*[*"
you could use:

> `(?<=UserDataGuid \[)([^\]]*)`

and then, you only match the GUID, and find it in the group #1
you can remove the parenthesis of group #1, because is a full match:

> `(?<=UserDataGuid \[)[^\]]*`

https://regex101.com/r/sI3kW4/1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want

```
(?<=UserDataGuid\s\[)([^\]]*)
```